# How to disable my midi-controller touch sensitivity in kontakt 5

Tags: piano, midi-controller-keyboard, fl-studio

i want to disable volume touch sensitivity of my midi-controller keyboard ( M-Audio avid key studio 49 ) in kontakt 5 ( emotional piano vst )
how do i do that?

Comment: by reading the manual.  it's different from keyboard to keyboard.  go to the manufacturer's website, download the manual, read.

Comment: There is no button for disabling volume sensitivity on the keyboard , in some other VSTs there is a Checkbox which allows you to ignore volume sensitivity , but not in this one :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to edit the volume sensitivity of your MIDI Controller, go to Options>MIDI Settings or Press F10. If you click on the button shown here, you can edit the curve of sensitivity.[image: Button]
This is the default.

[image: Default]

And if you want no sensitivity, you can do something like this.

[image: Flat]